# On Windows, how to access the directories of a Linux machine in the EC2 Amazon service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

On Windows, how to access the directories of a Linux machine in the EC2 Amazon service?

For example, commonly used "\ip...",
but how do we do that on a machine in the cloud by amazon EC2 service?

Observation -> to connect ssh to the server use the following command:

```
ssh -i "keys_acess" ubuntu@ec6-5-82-104-178.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: You can use `winscp`.

Comment: Windows now includes a `scp` client, you can use that.

Comment: I will test these two options, thank you very much.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As suggested by the comment @Marcin, I managed to transfer files using the winscp software, to do this, first of all, with cmd I had to connect via ssh to the EC2 instance, after that I accessed the root user with sudo su, and finally I gave permission to transferencia in the folder you want to transfer files with the command:

```
chmod 777 -R /destination/folder/location
```

In softwate winscp
go to -> new session -> in host put public ip of ec2 instance, you can find it in AWS online instance, connect part -> user set `ubuntu` -> password go to advanced -> SSH Authentication -> select the  public access key -> ok -> save -> connect

use this video if in doubt: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AodxudOScSQ&t=122s